# jquery maskedinput. How to check availability of the mask

Tags: jquery, mask, feature-detection, maskedinput

Can anyone help me with checking availability of the mask. I use this one:

```
if ($.isFunction($("#ID").mask)){
    var val = $("#ID").mask();
} else {
    var val = document.getElementById(ID).value;
}
```

but this condition is always TRUE. Don't matter written with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ID").mask("8 (999) 999-9999");
}
```

or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to verify if the `.mask()` function is available, you should try checking `$.fn.mask`.

If you're trying to verify whether an element has a mask, test if `$("#element").data("rawMaskFn")` is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! $("#element").data("rawMaskFn") - this is what i needed!